# Retag Privilege taken into account when proposing an edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, edits

I think that the privilege to [retag questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions) has become obsolete, now that one could propose an edit with only the changed tag and gain 2 rep from it.

But deleting the retag privilege and link should be wrong. So what I propose is, when proposing an edit, if the only change is a change of tag, and if the user who made the edit has the retag privilege, then the change is automatically applied and doesn't need to be approved.

**EDIT:** To clarify the situation let me give an example:

I wanted to make a retag, and I was half-asleep, I used the edit button instead of the retag button and only added the tag. I got 2 rep for it.

If I used the retag button it would have been taken automatically with no rep, and so it should have been in the scenario described previously.

Comment: Retag as a separate privilege [has been removed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege)

Comment: @Shog9 But there is still a bage for first retag.

Comment: It's still an *action* @convert, just a specialized edit.

Comment: @Shog9 And how to manage that action?

Comment: Edit the question and change the tags

Comment: @Shog9 What you mean by change the tags? Do I have to change all tags?

Comment: Nope. Add a tag, remove a tag, replace a tag ... That all counts as a "retag", @convert

Comment: @Shog9 Strange I added a tag and then removed it, but nothing hapend.

Comment: There's a couple of reasons why, @convert (starting with, if you undo the edit it won't count) - for full criteria, search for "organizer" [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732)

Comment: @Shog9 OK now I see the reason: "Edit the tags on a question asked by another user".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there was a **loophole** that allowed you to clog the queue with suggested edits that suggest **only** editing tags.

In practice this is was not a big issue:

1. People are limited to 1000 rep from suggested edits.
2. People servicing the queue will get "pissed off" and reject edits that abuse the queue in such a way, after 5 strikes in one day you will be banned from suggesting edits for a week.

That said, I just changed it so you **must** suggest more than a tag edit, if you have retag rights.

---

This privilege is still needed, the suggested edit queue is a scarce resource. We do not want to flood it with work that we know people are perfectly capable of doing without direct peer review.

Comment: Why not just auto-aprove if someone just changes the tag and has refag rights?   (Whats the point of an error message when the systems knows how to fix it's self)

Comment: its just to rare to need to do that, it would be a complex change

Comment: I agree with Ian. Since I normally do all retags through the edit button I found it pretty irritating to have the system complain when I retagged on a low rep site. I almost wouldn't have retried, because the error message sounded like a variation of the "you didn't edit enough" error.

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me too, that I accidentally choosed the way to edit, while a retag would have been the right way.

I explain my behaviour with the different, but similar looking user interfaces for accounts on different topics:

For example:

- link|edit|close|flag on German L&U, rep: 1840
- link|edit|retag|close|flag on Code Golf, rep: 797
- link|edit|retag|flag on Code Review, rep: 330
- link|edit|close|flag on StackExchange, rep: 4767

I used the edit-link before somewhere else, where it was appropriate, and didn't search for another link. I don't know why I can't retag on SE with 4k rep, but on CR with 330 rep. Yes, the borders are higher on SE, but of course it is a trap, to easy step into.

I opened a small [rant over here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/765/misguiding-error-message-on-tag-edit/766#766) about the misguiding error message; now I'm unsure, what to do.

From the user perspective, a silent acceptance of tag-edits would be preferable. At least the message could be improved - I didn't understand what it tried to tell me.

I suggest something like:

> To just retag a question without editing title or body, don't choose the edit-link but the retag-link.

Comment: try creating a new meta question tag with feature-request, you may get lots of surport.

Comment: [Did so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105666/156431)

Answer (score 1):

The privilege is still needed.

Yes you can do it via the edit route and gain 2 rep, but you can only gain a maximum of 1,000 points through edits so after a while you'll be doing this for no benefit.

Secondly do you really want to have all your retags approved?

Comment: That is my point, I find it ridiculous the way it is now, one shouldn't earn any rep for that if one have the retag privilege and I don't want to have retag approved, it was a mistake I made to use the edit, and I only noticed it after the fact