# Using the "edit" link to edit tags only submits to the approval queue, even though I have enough rep to retag

Tags: bug, tags, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retagging through suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78277/retagging-through-suggested-edits)

On stackoverflow.com, I submitted an edit to the approval queue and then went back to add a tag. I have nearly 1k rep, so more than enough to edit tags. Later I noticed that I got +4 rep for 2 "approved" edits on [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095076).

Should Stack Exchange have detected that I only changed the tags, and let the edit go through without approval? (and without the +2 rep?) Or do all tag edits need to be peer reviewed until a user has full edit privileges? (if that's the case, the `retag 100%` in my `/privileges` screen should be removed)

Comment: I think detecting tag only edits - while possible - wouldn't really be worth the effort. You just have to remember to hit the `retag` option rather than the `edit` link.

Comment: @ChrisF, that might well be, and I'm fine with that. But I can't imagine it being more than a few lines of code. ;-) OTOH, I kind of like having the option of a peer-reviewed tag edit in case I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing.

Comment: I've just tried this on Webmasters where I don't have edit rights and as long as I hit the `retag` link the change went through without needed review.

Comment: This was asked before need to find the question

Comment: @waffles Did you mean [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit)?

Comment: I would say that the best solution is for the retag rep to be "detected" and tag-only edits not submitted to the approval queue. However, if the user has submitted very few retags (under some limit?) perhaps tag edits should be submitted for review anyway, but take effect immediately? That way you get that second pair of eyes, if I'm a noob editor.