# Request for a better error message when retagging via edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, user-experience

When one has the [retag privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions), but not the edit privilege, then retagging using "edit" rather than "retag" gets one a confusing message:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - You have the privilege to retag questions; to suggest an edit please include a change to the title and/or the body as well

I suggest to change this into something like:

> To just retag a question without editing title or body, please step back, and don't choose the edit-link but the retag-link beneath.

Background:

I accidentally chose the "edit" link to retag a question, while using "retag" would have been the right way. I explain my behaviour with the different, but similar looking user interfaces for my accounts on different sites. For example:

- link|edit|close|flag on German L&U, rep: 1840
- link|edit|retag|close|flag on Code Golf, rep: 797
- link|edit|retag|flag on Code Review, rep: 330
- link|edit|close|flag on Stack Overflow, rep: 4767

I used the edit-link before somewhere else, where it was appropriate, and didn't search for another link.

The current error message assumes I intended to change body + tags, or headline + tags, but had forgotten to edit the other. But in reality, I had never planned to edit something else but the tags, and had the privilege to do so. I didn't understand what it tried to tell me, until I [ranted about it](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/765/misguiding-error-message-on-tag-edit/766#766) and it was explained to me by a moderator.

From the user perspective, a silent acceptance of tag-edits would be preferable. But that [has been discussed elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit/97717#97717), the result being *"it's too rare to need to do that, it would be a complex change"*. So at least the message could be improved.

This post might remind you about an answer I [posted yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit/105594#105594), but I was encouraged to open a new post on meta. So here we go.

Comment: As for your retag privileges on SO: these have been superseded by your edit privileges there. Hence no "retag" link for you any more. In other words: on Code Golf and Code Review it's kind of **`suggest edit|retag`** while on German L&U and SO it's **`edit`**. Confusing, yes. (But unrelated to the above, I feel, so I edited it out of the question.)

Comment: In the post where waffles explains that silently treating as just a retag is a lot of work, [he also writes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit/97717#97717): *"the suggested edit queue is a scarce resource. We do not want to flood it with work that we know people are perfectly capable of doing without direct peer review."* A better error message certainly would help avoiding people adding fake edits to title or body!

Comment: Retag as a separate privilege [has been removed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege)

Answer (score 1):

We have improved the error message you receive when the intent is only to retag a question.  Hopefully this clears up some confusion.