# Why should I use retag instead of edit?

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, retag-request

I have got two options to edit tags of a question:

1. use the **edit link** to edit the tags of a question and wait for a moderator to review and confirm it
2. use the **retag link** to modify the question tags without requiring any moderator to confirm the edit

While using the first approach will gain me 2 reputations for each edit, why should I go for the second approach?

Comment: Related: waffles' answer at [Retag Privilege taken into account when proposing an edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit/97717#97717), and [Request for a better errormessage for retagging via edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105666/request-for-a-better-errormessage-for-retagging-via-edit).

Comment: Retag as a separate privilege [has been removed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Submitting pure tag edits to the suggested edits queue [is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit/97717#97717) if you have the retag privilege, but not the edit privilege.

You'll get "You have the privilege to retag questions; to suggest an edit please include a change to the title and/or the body as well":

> [image]

Thus, it's not really a question of "why should you", but rather "you have to".

So, if you want to edit tags, you use the retag link, because you gotta. If you can make both the tags *and* post content better, you suggest an edit.

Comment: Right now I have the **retage questions**, but not the **edit questions and answers** privilege; but I can do pure tag edit.

Comment: @Meysam That's weird. Maybe it works if you're adding tags (I tried removing one), or maybe there are just special rules for SO specifically. The screenshot is fresh; I tried it with this very question.

Comment: So the system *knows* the above example edit was actually a retag. Why doesn't it silently treat it as such? (Not awarding the 2 reputation either.)

Comment: @Meysam, did you also type an edit comment? And lunboks, did you type "edited tags" manually?

Comment: @Arjan I did type that manually, but it doesn't work with other edit summaries, either.

Comment: @Arjan Yes I typed an edit comment

Comment: Ah, silently treating as a retag [has already been discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit/97717#97717) as being *"its just to rare to need to do that, it would be a complex change"*.

Answer (score 2):

You will gain up to 1000 points with the **edit link**, once that has been achieved, there will be no difference.

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation):

> You can only earn a maximum of **+1000** total reputation through suggested edits, however.

The retag existed before on page editing was possible, so in some sense it is vestigial.

As for why go for the second approach - if you will not gain rep using the first one and only tags need to be updated, this is a cleaner UI, where only the tag edit area appears.

Comment: So I conclude that it's better to use the **edit link** approach until all the +1000 reputation is gained. right?

Comment: @Meysam - Better? If you are looking for rep, yes.

Comment: @Meysam It's better only in one case: if you improve something else in the post, e.g. grammar mistakes or readability. Otherwise it's sheer "rep hunting" which in my opinion is rude.

Comment: And, Meysam, a suggested edit might be rejected if reviewers think it's just not substantial enough (eg: if it's actually just a retag). Or if reviewers think it's just rep hunting, like @Shadow noted.

Comment: And, @Meysam, note [waffles' remark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit/97717#97717): *"the suggested edit queue is a scarce resource. We do not want to flood it with work that we know people are perfectly capable of doing without direct peer review."*